# How to display weather using any weather website

Tags: java-me, midp

I am supposed to develop an application in which I am supposed to display weather conditions. When I enter a city that time it should get connected to any weather site suppose `weather.com`, and display only the weather conditions like humidity, rainfall, temperature, etc that is all sorts of weather conditions. But it should not display the complete web-page.

We are supposed to work on SDK-3.0 - in which it shows us the model of mobiles and we have to code which will be implemented on that mobile model.

So how do I connect to internet? And later how will I display only the weather on the mobile of SDK, because internet always keep on changing its format?

I am completely new to J2ME+MIDlets, and this is my first application in j2me. I want to know the detailed procedure for how to do this.

Comment: What a horrible writting. Please, proof read the question before posting it!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Yahoo Weather API](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/).

Have in mind that Yahoo explicitly states that their API is for non-commercial use though.

To parse the RSS returned by the API I'd recommend an XML pull parser. You'll find more information on those [here](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/parsingxml/).